# wordpress website menu behind content

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

im having the problem of the menu on my WordPress website appearing behind the content on multiple pages. iv been looking online for a solution and iv looked at the z-index and have been using different values to apply but still no luck.

i would appreciate any help at all

my website is: [www.thehelpingworld.com](http://www.thehelpingworld.com)

(p.s. please note that the collapsable menu appears when width of screen is below 800px)

thank you in advance

CODE FOR MENU:

```
.sf-menu ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
.sf-menu ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
* html .sf-menu ul {
    height: 1%;
    }
*:first-child+html .sf-menu ul {
    min-height: 1px;
    }
.sf-menu ul {
    display: block;
    }

.sf-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
.sf-menu li ul {
    top: -999em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    }
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    top: 40px;
    }
.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -999em;
    }
.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 170px;
    }
.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -999em;
    }
.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 170px;
    }
.sf-menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    visibility: inherit;
    }
.sf-menu li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Oswald, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
.sf-menu li a:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > a,
.sf-menu li.current_page_item > a,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-item > a,
.sf-menu li.current-menu-parent > a,
.sf-menu li.current-page-parent > a,
.sf-menu li.current-page-ancestor > a,
.sf-menu li.current_page_ancestor > a {
    }
.sf-menu li:hover li a,
.sf-menu li.sfHover li a {
    width: 140px;
    }

#top-navigation {
    background: #333;
    }
#top-navigation ul {
    border-left: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#top-navigation li ul {
    }
#top-navigation li:hover ul,
#top-navigation li.sfHover ul {
    top: 40px;
    background: #333;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#top-navigation li li:hover ul,
#top-navigation li li.sfHover ul {
    top: -1px;
    border-left: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#top-navigation li {
    border-right: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#top-navigation li li {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#top-navigation li a {
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 40px;
    }
#top-navigation li a:hover,
#top-navigation li.sfHover > a,
#top-navigation li.current_page_item > a,
#top-navigation li.current-menu-item > a,
#top-navigation li.current-menu-parent > a,
#top-navigation li.current-page-parent > a,
#top-navigation li.current-page-ancestor > a,
#top-navigation li.current_page_ancestor > a {
    color: #fff;
    }
#top-navigation li:hover li a,
#top-navigation li.sfHover li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: normal;
    }

#main-navigation {
    border: solid #333;
    border-width: 1px 0 3px;
    }
#main-navigation li a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
#main-navigation .sf-menu > ul > li:after {
    width: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 16px;
    content: "/";
    display: block;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
#main-navigation .sf-menu > ul > li:last-child:after {
    display: none;
    }
#main-navigation li:hover ul,
#main-navigation li.sfHover ul {
    top: 50px;
    background: #333;
    }
#main-navigation li li:hover ul,
#main-navigation li li.sfHover ul {
    top: -1px;
    border-left: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#main-navigation li li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #565656;
    }
#main-navigation li li a {
    color: #a6a6a6;
    }
#main-navigation li a:hover,
#main-navigation li.sfHover > a,
#main-navigation li.current_page_item > a,
#main-navigation li.current-menu-item > a,
#main-navigation li.current-menu-parent > a,
#main-navigation li.current-page-parent > a,
#main-navigation li.current-page-ancestor > a,
#main-navigation li.current_page_ancestor > a {
    color: #1fa0ae;
    }
#main-navigation li:hover li a,
#main-navigation li.sfHover li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: normal;
    }
```

Comment: Please include code in your question. By providing a link like you did you risk many smart people ignoring your question because they do not want to debug your whole site.

Comment: thank you for the advice RUJordan, iv mended the post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a positive `z-index` to the `#main-navigation > .sf-menu > ul` class, will make the dropdown menu appear in front of the page content.

```
#main-navigation > .sf-menu > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 16em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
}
```

would become

```
#main-navigation > .sf-menu > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 16em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: thank you but i just tried it and had no luck, still the same issue

Comment: This answer is correct. #main-navigation > .sf-menu > ul is at line 502 of themes/fashionistas/style.css.